# How can I perform a one-client MITM attack in a Diffie-Hellman key exchange?

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptanalysis, diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm

Suppose we have intercepted a public key exchange (via Diffie-Hellman protocol). In addition to the keys **A** and **B**, the generator **g** and the module **p** are known.

Assuming that it is possible to exchange keys with client B, once it has finished the conversation with A, how can I obtain the private exponent of B?

I had thought about the "*Small subgroup confinement attack*", but I'm not sure it's the best way.

Take this challenge (static client) as a reference : [Link](https://cryptohack.org/challenges/diffie-hellman/).
I'm trying to learn, maybe the answer will be trivial!

Comment: The question is asking about a (permanent) challenge, which is off-topic. Also it's ill-posed: it's about MitM, but the first two sentences are about a passive eavesdropping, which opposes MitM. It's wanted to _"obtain the private exponent"_, of a party, which MitM or small subgroup confinement attack does not allow.

Comment: Hint: in this CTF, you won't "obtain the private exponent" of either Alice or Bob. You'll obtain the flag encrypted under an AES key derived from a shared secret that you can compute, because you know the private exponent that you used.